# jQuery $.ajax on mongoDB result

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating a little API with express and mongo, so I'm trying this

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res){
  mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/portailDb', function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var collection = db.collection('projets');

        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {

            res.json(results);
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

I have no problems with this code the result is:

```
[
  {
    "test": {
      "login": "loginTest",
      "psw": "pswTest"
    },
    "_id": "5310e8f5683411b304dabfa7"
  },
  {
    "test": {
      "login": "loginTest",
      "psw": "pswTest"
    },
    "_id": "5310e95306184cc204e66e72"
  },
  {
    "test": {
      "login": "loginTest",
      "psw": "pswTest"
    },
    "_id": "5310e9f950a929db04087e15"
  }
]
```

When I want to GET this with jQuery I have this error `Uncaught parsererror`

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response) {
            jsonObj = response;
            console.log(jsonObj);
        },
        error: function(e, xhr){
            throw xhr;
        }
    });
```

I think it's due to the [ ] who surround the mongo result.

Have you got any solutions for this ?

Thank a lot

Comment: That's valid JSON alright (per JSONLint) -- you can try `res.send(arr)` -- although I believe `res.json` calls `res.send`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's truely the entire result, it looks like the dataType isn't `jsonp` but is rather `json`.  That presumes you're not posting cross-domain though.

Comment: if I pass dataType to "json" jQuery return this error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Sounds like the "presumes you're not posting cross-domain" assumption doesn't hold up.  Alas, your result is not jsonp, which is the source of your error.